# Como chamar RESTful Web Services em aplicação Android?

Tags: android, web-service

Gostaria de saber como desenvolver uma aplicação que utilize web services do tipo RESTful?

Que biblioteca eu preciso para criar um app com web service do tipo RESTful?

Answer (score 1):

A melhor e mais utilizada forma de acessar `API`s no Android é usando o Retrofit.

Você pode seguir um pequeno passo-a-passo para instalar e configurar o Retrofit no [site oficial no **Github**](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) e caso precise de informações mais avançadas, acessar o código fonte, acompanhar ou reportar *issues* basta ir direto no [repositório do projeto no **Github**](https://github.com/square/retrofit)

Tem uma série de [tutoriais sobre ele bem interessante](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client)

Espero ter ajudado \o/

P.S.: Obrigado pela observação sobre o link, Diego.